# How to change CultureInfo.CurrentCulture in a C#/Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, globalization

I want `string.Format()` and `.ToString()` calls to use invariant culture, not the system culture.

`System.Globalisation.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` property is read-only in Windows Store apps, so it cannot be changed directly, unlike in .NET 4.6 and later.

I tried using `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` (which should work according to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), but it does not change anything:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var c1 = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
Task.Run(delegate
{
    var c2 = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
});
```

After the above code executes, c1 and c2 still contain my local system culture, not the invariant culture. `string.Format` still produces strings using my local culture settings.

Surely there must be a way to change culture of a thread?

Comment: Are you able to set `Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride`?

Comment: @mjwills This seems to be working, thank you! Although strangely it does not work instantly, only after some time has passed. Plus I don't know how to specify "invariant" language (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).

Answer (score 0):

I have added following code to my `App.Xaml.cs` constructor. (Just after `this.InitializeComponent();`)
It worked for me.

```
var culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```